# ¿Cómo pintar un marcador del mapa de Google Maps en Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo un mapa con varios marcadores, al seleccionar cada marcador debería pintarlo, es decir, pintar el punto o marcador seleccionado. Si pinté un marcador y selecciono otro, el primer marcador debería despintarse y el segundo pintarse.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esta situación?.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que se despinte el primero y se pinte el segundo, cierto? Pusiste esto en tu pregunta: *Si pinté un marcador y selecciono otro, el **primer** marcador debería despintarse y el **primero** pintarse*. Sí ese es el caso sería bueno que edites la pregunta para no caer en confusiones.

Comment: si , asi es  Flxtr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres agregar ese tipo de funcionalidad, debes crear un `Listener` de click para tu mapa de google. Dentro de este `Listener` existe un metodo que se llama `onMarkerClick` el cual recibe el `Marker`

```
Marker prevMarker;

TU_MAPA.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        if (prevMarker != null) {
            prevMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }

        if (!marker.equals(prevMarker)) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            prevMarker = marker;
        }
        prevMarker = marker;
        return false;
    }

});
```

La variable `prevMarker` es para mantener el marker al cual de le dan click, asi saber cual tiene que volver a su antiguo color. Siendo null en el primer caso y diferente al marker por el click, pintas el marker, y `prevMarker` pasaria a ser el del click. En el segundo intento, como `prevMarker` ya no es null, vuelve a su color original, en el otro `if` como no son iguales, MARCA el `marker` al cual dieron click y lo setea nuevamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias sioesi, funciona perfecto!!

Comment: saludos @devjav exito!